# Phonegap and Blackberry WebWorks: build\StandardInstall does not exist

Tags: blackberry, ant, cordova

My environment is Windows XP.
JDK and Apache ant are installed.
Phonegap version is 1.7.0
BlackBerry Webworks SDK for smartphone: version 2.3.1

I'm following the instruction of http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Blackberry to try phonegap on blackberry.

The sample Blackberry WebWorks sample application I use is this https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/tree/master/lib/blackberry/sample

First I execute 'ant blackberry build'. Although it said "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", however, neither StandardInstall nor .cod was created. And the output contained error message like this:

```
[exec] E:\Temp\widgetGen.15924526831337325595265.tmp\extension\blackberry\common\util\URLDecoder.java:183: unclosed string literal
[exec]         decodingMap.put( "%AC", "? );
[exec]                                 ^
[exec] 100 errors
[exec] Error!: Error: java compiler failed: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin\javac.exe @E:\TEMP\rapc_02802fef.dir\options
[exec] [ERROR]                     RAPC exception occurred
```

The full build log is here http://www.cis.nctu.edu.tw/~gis90571/a.txt

Then I execute 'ant blackberry load-simulator', it shows:
...

BUILD FAILED
D:\WebWorks_projects\helloworld\build.xml:33: The following error occurred while
 executing this line:

D:\WebWorks_projects\helloworld\blackberry.xml:123: D:\WebWorks_projects\hellowo
rld\build\StandardInstall does not exist.

the content of blackberry.xml is:

```
123: <copy todir="${simulator.dir}">
124:   <fileset dir="${build.dir}/StandardInstall" includes="*.cod, *.cso, *.csl, *.alx" />
125: </copy>
```

(I put the sample app provided by phonegap in D:\WebWorks_projects and changed its name to "helloworld".)

I'm new to ant and blackberry.

Could someone please offer some help or hint? Thanks.

Answer:
It seems that the source file URLDecoder.java in \ext\common\blackberry\common\util is broken due to some encoding issue. Fix it and the problem solved.

An useful article here: http://whatdrewknows.blogspot.com/2012/04/cordova-blackberry-development-part-2.html

Comment: As u say your build was successful… Did you got the .cod file which will be present in StandardInstall?

Comment: in "build" subfolder, I got a file "CordovaSample.zip" and a subfolder "widget". No .cod file.

Comment: A StandardInstall folder should be created after successful building of the app.The application .cod file is generated inside that folder.

Comment: I see. I thought the building was successful because executing 'ant blackberry build' said "BUILD SUCCESSFUL". I will update the question.

Comment: Post your entire built time log as well as your config.xml's content tag

Comment: hi Coder_sLaY, I'm currently uploading full log to someplace. Please wait a minute. I don't modify config.xml, still the same as the question pointing to.

Comment: hi, i am new to blackberry platform however i also treid the same thing as mentioned above and got stuck in the same situation, not getting any OTAInstaller and StandardInstall folder. Will you plz tell me how did you overcome this issue? Needs help.

Comment: hi @yehnan will you please share your steps as i am in the same situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application is not successfully getting built.

If your application gets build and generate 3 folders

1. OTAInstall
2. StandardInstall
3. widget

As well as one application.zip file is also created.

If you get all these files then your application was successfully compiled and built.

Comment: Thanks. All the files you said got built finally. Simulator is launched successfully but my sample application can't be loaded.

Comment: I succeed! I found a useful article here http://whatdrewknows.blogspot.com/2012/04/cordova-blackberry-development-part-2.html  Well, I don't know why I couldn't see the sample application in simulator. But it shows now. Thanks a lot to you, Coder_sLaY.

Comment: Congrats…. Let me know if you need anymore Help :)